# TYPO3 User Management

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I think only one thing is missing...
but I do not get this point :p
i created an user and I created a group, both didn't work

What I want is a group with specific rights, one with read and edit rights and one with only read rights, but all only works for the "root page"
how can I inherit this to the following pages?

All the things from older versions of TYPO3 do not really work at my version (my version is 7.6.14)

Update 1:
Okey, I could set the rights by hand for every single page in the access category. But I think there should be a possibility to inherit the rights to all the subpages?

At last it may only be one checkbox ore option I have to activate?

One picture to make it more clearly what my problem is:
[image]

For those who don't understand german, "Berechtigungen" means access and "Tiefe" means depth.

**Solution**
I finally got it and it and it is working fine.
I just need to set the depth at the right place here:
[image]

One more hint: be_acl is a good extention, if you need more than one group for a page or more specific rights for different users.

Comment: be more specific about your groups and editing: are you working in BE (backend) or FE (frontend)? In BE it should be obvious. And you always will need at least two groups/users to verify your configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the group does not have access to the subpages?

In the backend under `System` -> `Access` you can change the ownership of pages -
 owner, group and all.

When editing access control of one page, you can change the *depth* to automatically adjust subpages.

Comment: Thank you for your idea. I updated my post. I can give the rights there only by hand for every single page. But i dont know how to inherit the rights to all the subpages. "Depth" only show me more subpages but do not give me the possibility to set the rights for all subpages at once.

Comment: Do yo usee the "edit" icon in the screenshot beside each page name? Click that. That's what I meant with "editing access control".

Comment: oh yeah thank you vermy much
it was just this missing depth there at the right place...
finally i got it and it is working :)

Answer (score 1):

You can find a really good article about right management in the blog from Marcus Schwemer here: https://typo3worx.eu/2017/02/typo3-backend-user-management/

For other things it would be useful if you could provide a little bit more informations about what does not work?

For example it could be that your user has no access to the page tree, if this is the case there is an extra "Access" Backend module. You can find more information about this [here](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/InsideTypo3Reference/CoreArchitecture/AccessControl/AccessControlOptions/Index.html#page-permissions).

Comment: Thank you. It is the last point with the page tree. I added some Information to my post.

Comment: You can read all the necessary informations about the page permissions in this tutorial: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/GettingStartedTutorial/UserManagement/PagePermissions/Index.html#page-permissions 

This should explain all.